# Printf spaces if number < 10 using only printf

Tags: alignment, printf

So, i have three numbers that can be < 100;

How can i printf those numbers to look like this:

```
{10, 5,20}
{ 1, 6, 2}
{19,18, 7}
```

instead of this

```
{10,5,20}
{1,6,2}
{19,18,7}
```

and it is possible to use only printf(no ifs)?

Comment: Did you check the man page for printf? Which part you did not understand?

Comment: It's C or C++, pick one or I'll remove both.

Comment: Maybe all you need is [a good reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? Or [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: Use `%2d` ? like [this](https://ideone.com/Rau6eF)

Comment: `printf("{%2d,%2d,%2d}\n",i,j,k);` would do it for you.. Checking the manual for commands is strongly suggested though ;) Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("%2d", yournumber)` will print number with 2 characters. If number is less than 2 chars long, spaces will be included before number.

In case number is bigger than 2 digits, modifier has no effect and entire number will be printed.

```
printf("%2d", 1);   //  " 1"
printf("%2d", 10);  //  "10"
printf("%2d", 100); // "100"
```

Comment: Why 10, specifically?

Comment: Oops, I mislead. It should be `2` as 10 are 2 digits.

Comment: `print number with 2 characters.` is not the right explanation I'm afraid. It just sets the width of the field to 2 chars, may be?

Comment: @sjsam it sets width to `2` characters, not `10`? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the width of the field using "%2d", you can change 2 for the width that you like.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%2d,%2d,%2d\n", 10,5,20);
    return 0;
}
```